ImageMagickで画像に文字を合成する際の annotate、label、captionの違いについて
Q1.ImageMagickで画像に文字を合成する際、annotate、label、captionのいずれのオプションを選択するか、どう判断すればよいですか？
現状の理解
・label … 画像に文字を合成する際に使用。長い文字列は折り返しされない
・caption … 画像に文字を合成する際に使用。長い文字列は折り返しされる
・annotate … どういうときにこのオプションを使用するのかよく分かりません。annotateオプションを使用しないとできないことはありますか？
Q2.annotate、label、captionオプションｓはいずれも単独使用のみ可ですか？　併用は不可？

参考: Difference between caption, draw, annotate, label while adding text to ImageMagick
